# Help parsing simple JSON (using JSON for JAVA ME)

Tags: java, json, parsing, java-me

I new to parsing JSON - up until this point, I've been purely XML.  Anyways, I am using JSON (Java ME) to parse something with the following structure:

```
{"name" : "JACK","name" : "JILL","name" : "JOHN","name" : "JENNY","name" : "JAMES","name" : "JIM"}
```

Here is my code:

```
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray jsonArray = outer.getJSONArray("name");
        System.out.println("ARRAY SIZE:"
                + jsonArray.length());
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
    }
```

My problem is that I cannot even get the println("ARRAY SIZE:"...) statement to output at all in my Eclipse console.  The only time that I am getting any sort of output is if I use the following code:

```
try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
        System.out.println("OUTPUT:"
                + json.getString("name"));
    } catch (JSONException ex) {
    }
```

...That seems to give me only the last element.  Is there a reason why I cannot get the JSONArray to work?  Is it because the JSON contains no "outer" key?

I'd appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: Try it this way: `{"names":["JACK","JILL","JOHN","JENNY","JAMES","JIM"]}`

Comment: A general hint in Java programming: don't suppress/swallow exceptions. Just throw them or at least print them by `ex.printStackTrace()`. They contain invaluable information about the cause of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. Just removed the exception handling to minimize the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key must be unique. You need to differentiate those "name"'s by using "Name1", "Name2", ... etc

Comment: Unfortunately, the JSON is being returned by a web service out of my control. I will have to take it up with them. Good to know, though - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Hi create one json file like format.... `{"name1" : "JACK","name2" : "JILL","name3" : "JOHN","name4" : "JENNY","name5" : "JAMES","name6" : "JIM"}`
& save this file in WEB-INF Folder on server & get response from server with reading this file... 
Thanks