# SQL LIKE operator to find words in stored JSON

Tags: sql, json, sql-like

I have this JSON stored in DB:
Column name: json

```
- '{"brand":"1","year":"2008","model":"2","price":"2001212","category":"Category Example"}'
- '{"brand":"1","year":"2008","model":"2","price":"2001212","category":"Category Example2"}'
```

I want to make a search using Like operator to find all categories with "Category" word:

At this moment Im doing it this way, but only return a complete phrase:

```
select * from table where json like '%"category":"Category Example"%';
```

How can I build a query that returns all categories with "Category word"?

Updated:

I'm using MySQL
Thanks

Comment: You should store that data in a table rather than a column.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? There may be tools which could help with this (e.g. recent versions of Postgres include a JSON datatype). However, as Musa says, the need to perform this kind of query does suggest that normalising that data into a full table of its own would be a good idea.

Comment: `categories with "Category" word` or `categories with "Category word"`, which will it be?

Comment: Im using MySQL, and as Musa said the best way is using a Table.  But, in this moment I have to store data as JSON.

Answer (score 6):

While undeclared this looks like a Postgres question.

There are hardly any JSON-processing tool in the current version 9.2.
But [a whole set of tools](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) will be shipped with the upcoming **Postgres 9.3** [currently in beta](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/roadmap/).

I interpret your question as:

*Find all rows where the json column contains one or more fields named 'category' holding a value that contains the string 'Category'.*

[One ore more?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306741/do-json-keys-need-to-be-unique) Not sure if Postgres enforces uniqueness, I don't have a 9.3 installation at hand.

With Postgres 9.3, your query could look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  json->>'category' LIKE '%Category%'
```

`->>` .. "Get JSON object field as text"

Use `ILIKE` for a case insensitive search.

More in this related answer:
[How do I query using fields inside the new PostgreSQL JSON datatype?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10560394/how-do-i-query-using-fields-inside-the-new-postgresql-json-datatype/10560761#10560761)

Comment: I didnt know that.  Im using MySQL right now. In any case, +1 for a helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use a library? The "common schema" library offers a function that does just what you need:

http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/extract_json_value.html

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I asked a really bad question, because I could make the search using Regexp.

I found this solution.  Maybe this is not the fastest way, but does what I need:

```
select * from table where json regexp '"category":"([^"]*)Category([^"]*)"';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```
select * from table where json @> '{"category":"Category Example"}';
```