# Looping through multidimensional array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops, each

So as the example below show I want to loop through an array inside an jQuery plugin that I'm trying to build. It's not working so can somebody help me with this.

```
$.each(defaults.garage, function(i, value){

    $.each(value.cars, function(i2, value2){

        alert(value2.model);

    }); 

});

$.fn[pluginName].defaults = {
      garage:[
            {
                name: '',
                country:'',
                cars:[
                        {
                            model: '',
                            year:''

                        },
                        {
                            model: '',
                            year:''

                        }

                ],
                hook: function(){}
            }       
        ],
        garage:[
            {
                name: '',
                country:'',
                cars:[
                        {
                            model: '',
                            year:''

                        },
                        {
                            model: '',
                            year:''

                        }

                ],
                hook: function(){}
            }       
        ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is due to the object keys not being unique.

[Do JSON keys need to be unique?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306741/do-json-keys-need-to-be-unique)

You can use this:

```
$.each(garages, function(i,v){
    $.each(garages[i].cars, function(i2, v2){
        alert(garages[i].cars[i2].model);
    })
})

garages = [
    {
        name: '',
        country: '',
        cars:[
            {
                model: 'BMW',
                year: ''
            }
        ],
        hook: function(){}
    }

    {
        name: '',
        country: '',
        cars:[
            {
                model: 'Honda',
                year: ''
            }
        ],
        hook: function(){}
    }

]
```

[here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bXNB9/)