# JSON.parse is removing 2 objects from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I am currently experiencing this weird issue.

I have a valid JSON object just like this:

```
var myjson = '[{"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}}, {"text": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"},"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"},"text": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}}]';
```

Then I proceed to transform it into a normal javascript array of objects like so:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(myjson);
console.log(parsed);
```

For some weird reason the parsed Array only contains the first and last object ....

I have prepared a fiddle for this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ph5ubvzy/1/)

Comment: Because your second object has the same key three times, it's not actually four objects in an array.

Comment: does this mean I have to change it to [{"text1": {....}}, {"text2": {....}}, ... ] ?

Comment: Nno, you only need one fix or the other; that one has both, which is redundant.

Comment: You are missing a couple brackets if you intended to have an array with a bunch of objects.  No problem with the objects having the same keys as long as they are seperate objects - this should work: `var myjson = '[{"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}}, {"text": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"}}, {"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"}},{"text": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}}]';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the same key multiple times, the last one will overwrite all previous ones. Use unique keys or put the values of those keys in an array instead. In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16894540/1422070) there is a link to the original spec declaring that this should be the case.

Edit: [here's an example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpz24pbx/1/)

```
var myjson = '[{"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}}, {"text1": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"},"text2": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"},"text3": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}}]';

// OR
var myjsonarray = '[{"text": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}}, [{"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"}, {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"},{"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}]]'
```

Comment: could you update my fiddle with your example? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: @noa-dev note that if you'd used a stack snippet it would be visible inline and easily copied to an answer

Comment: @noa-dev sure I added a link to a fiddle

Comment: oh man... time to take a break today .. such a fail. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A JSON Object looks like the following

```
public JSONObject(Map<?, ?> map) {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    if (map != null) {
        for (final Entry<?, ?> e : map.entrySet()) {
            final Object value = e.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                this.map.put(String.valueOf(e.getKey()), wrap(value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A JSON Object is basically a hashmap containing key value pair.

When we provide the same key again and again it gets overwritten. So, you are getting only the first and last value.

If you still want to have with same name and to have in a single wrapper you may try with this

```
[
 {"text": 
   {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}
 }, 
 [
   {"text": 
      {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"}
   }, 
   {"text": 
      {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"}
   },
   {"text": 
      {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}
   }
 ]
]
```

Have a look at this [JSON Object java implementation](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java) to know in depth.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON file may be valid, but that doesn't mean that it has the structure you intend it to have ;)

Right now, the array contains indeed two objects. In the second object you define 'text' three times, each time overwritiong the previous declaration. So you have the first text, and then the second and third get overwritten by the fourth.

Comment: oh man... time to take a break today .. such a fail. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have given each key same name that the problem. **[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/ph5ubvzy/2/)**

```
var myjson = '[{"text1": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 1"}}, {"text2": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content1"},"text3": {"tag": "question","content": "question content 2"},"text4": {"tag": "answer","content": "answer content2"}}]';

console.log(myjson);
var parsed = JSON.parse(myjson);
console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: oh man... time to take a break today .. such a fail. Thank you

Comment: Still the json is valid but formate is little bit confusing will be hard in accessing the data i am updating the fiddle, just wait for it :)

Comment: Now check the fiddle its all ok now :) Easy for you to access the data.