# OrientDB ETL create edge using multiple fields in match criteria

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-etl

I have some data that I'm tracking that looks something like this:

node.csv

```
Label1,Label2
Alpha,A
Alpha,B
Alpha,C
Bravo,A
Bravo,B
```

The pair `Label1` and `Label2` define a unique entry in this data set.

I have another table that has some values in it that I want to link to the vertices created in `Table1`:

data.csv

```
Label1,Label2,Data
Alpha,A,10
Alpha,A,20
Alpha,B,30
Bravo,A,99
```

I'd like to generate edges from entries in `Data` to `Node` when both `Label1` and `Label2` fields match in each.

In this case, I'd have:

```
Data(Alpha,A,10) ---> Node(Alpha,A)
Data(Alpha,A,20) ---> Node(Alpha,A)
Data(Alpha,B,30) ---> Node(Alpha,B)
Data(Bravo,A,99) ---> Node(Bravo,A)
```

In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39517796/orientdb-etl-edge-transformer-2-joinfieldnames) it appears that this issue gets solved by simply adding an extra "joinFieldName" entry into the json file, but I'm not getting the same result with my data.

My node.json file looks like:

```
{
    "config": { "log": "info" },
    "source": { "file": { "path": "./node.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": {} },
    "transformers": [ { "vertex": { "class": "Node" } } ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:test.orientdb",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "classes": [ {"name": "Node", "extends": "V"} ],
            "indexes": []
        }
    }
}
```

and my data.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "config": { "log": "info" },
    "source": { "file": { "path": "./data.csv" } },
    "extractor": { "csv": { } },
    "transformers": [
            { "vertex": { "class": "Data" } },
            { "edge":   { "class":         "Source",
                          "joinFieldName": "Label1",
                          "lookup":        "Node.Label1",
                          "joinFieldName": "Label2",
                          "lookup":        "Node.Label2",
                          "direction":     "in"
                        }
            }
        ],
    "loader": {
        "orientdb": {
            "dbURL": "plocal:test.orientdb",
            "dbType": "graph",
            "batchCommit": 1000,
            "classes": [ {"name": "Data",   "extends": "V"},
                         {"name": "Source", "extends": "E"}
                       ],
            "indexes": []
        }
    }
}
```

After I run these, I get this output when I query the result:

```
orientdb {db=test.orientdb}> SELECT FROM V

+----+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+----+-------------+
|#   |@RID |@CLASS|Label1|Label2|out_Source         |Data|in_Source    |
+----+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+----+-------------+
|0   |#25:0|Node  |Alpha |A     |[#41:0,#43:0,#47:0]|    |             |
|1   |#26:0|Node  |Alpha |B     |[#45:0]            |    |             |
|2   |#27:0|Node  |Alpha |C     |                   |    |             |
|3   |#28:0|Node  |Bravo |A     |[#42:0,#44:0,#48:0]|    |             |
|4   |#29:0|Node  |Bravo |B     |[#46:0]            |    |             |
|5   |#33:0|Data  |Alpha |A     |                   |10  |[#41:0,#42:0]|
|6   |#34:0|Data  |Alpha |A     |                   |20  |[#43:0,#44:0]|
|7   |#35:0|Data  |Alpha |B     |                   |30  |[#45:0,#46:0]|
|8   |#36:0|Data  |Bravo |A     |                   |99  |[#47:0,#48:0]|
+----+-----+------+------+------+-------------------+----+-------------+

9 item(s) found. Query executed in 0.012 sec(s).
```

This is incorrect.  I don't want Edges #42:0, #44:0, #46:0 and #47:0:

```
#42:0 connects Node(Bravo,A) and Data(Alpha,A)
#44:0 connects Node(Bravo,A) and Data(Alpha,A)
#46:0 connects Node(Bravo,B) and Data(Alpha,B) 
#47:0 connects Node(Alpha,A) and Data(Bravo,A)
```

It looks like adding multiple `joinFieldName` entries in the transformer is resulting in an OR operation, but I'd like an 'AND' here.

Does anyone know how to fix this?  I'm not sure what I'm doing differently than the other StackOverflow question...

Comment: have you figured out the fix for this? I have the similar issue.

Comment: I figured out a workaround and thought of sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

After debugging the ETL code, I figured out a workaround. As you said, there is no way to make the multiple `joinFieldName`s forms one edge. Each `joinFieldName` will create an edge.

What you can do is, generate an extra column in the CSV file by concatenating "Label1" and "Label2" and use `lookup` query in `edge` transformation, something like, assume your data.csv has one extra field like `label1_label2` and the values of that field are something like "label1====label2`.

Your edge transformation should have the following

```
{ "edge":   { "class": "Source",
              "joinFieldName": "label1_label2",
              "lookup": "select expand(n) from (match {class: Node, as: n} return n) where n.Label1+'===='+n.Label2 = ?",
              "direction": "in"
            }
 }
```

Don't forget to `expand` the vertex otherwise, ETL thinks that it is a Document. The trick here is to write one query by concatenating multiple fields and passing the equivalent `joinFieldName`.

Comment: I'll have to try that out.  For importing my nodes, I added a "field" transformer to concatenate the keys using something like `{ "field": {"fieldName": "MergedKey", "expressin": "Label1.append(':').append(Label2)"} },` to generate a "MergedKey" field that had entries like `Label1:Label2` to import my nodes.  Then to import my data entries, I did the same thing to create a MergedKey entry there and then I removed the field after I created the edge in the `transformers` section.  It still pollutes my node data by keeping that merged key around though.  I wish there was a cleaner way to do this.