# How to expand JSON structure in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON structure, which is small.
My requirement is to expand the JSON structure.

**Example JSON structure**   :

```
'{  
   "CallLog":{  
      "Three":{  
         "age":100,
         "name":"Sample",
         "Other":100,
         "Add":"Sample"
      },
      "One":{  
         "CallLogEntry":[  
            {  
               "ContryCode":{  
                  "CountryCode":123
               }
            },
            {  
               "Phone Number":{  
                  "PhoneNumber":456
               }
            },
            {  
               "Name":{  
                  "name":456
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "Two":{  
         "age":100,
         "name":"Sample",
         "Other":100,
         "Add":"Sample"
      }


     }
    }
```

So, i want to expand his JSON.
Lets say i want repeat "One" node 10 times, and "two" node 5 times, and then write this expanded JSON in the new JSON. 
How can i do this?

Comment: Can you write out in your question an example of the desired result? I'm not 100% sure if I understand but I think it's not possible to do since you would have duplicate keys http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306741/do-json-keys-need-to-be-unique

Comment: parse the json, use the parsed object to fill a new object with desired additions, serialize the new object to get the new json. (something like that)

Comment: @RC.                          How can i do that. ?

Comment: @altoids       {
 "CallLog": {
  
  "One": {
   "CallLogEntry": [
    {
     "ContryCode": {
      "CountryCode": 123
     }
    },
    {
     "Phone Number": {
      "PhoneNumber": 456
     }
    },
    {
     "Name": {
      "name": 456
     }
    },
    
    {
     "ContryCode": {
      "CountryCode": 123
     }
    },
    {
     "Phone Number": {
      "PhoneNumber": 456
     }
    },
    {
     "Name": {
      "name": 456
     }
    }
   
   ]
  }
 }
}

Comment: what java json library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it through java, i would recommend converting this JSON to java code first.Once you get the corresponding classes e.g. CallLog.java,CallLogEntry.java etc , you can define a new Class CallLog1.java and declare 10 'One' , 5 'Two' etc ,  as per your requirement and then create the JSON object. You can copy paste your json to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to get POJO , and then create you own POJO , and convert it into JSON , using library like GSon.