# Converting object containing list of data to json array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My for loop looks like this,

```
var myObj = data.response.carTypes;
  for (var key in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(myObj[key]);
    }}
```

output on console looks like this,

```
car1
car2
car3
```

i want to convert this data something like this,

```
$scope.myArray = [{"cars":car1}, {"cars":car2}, {"cars":car3}]
```

how can I convert it this way in javascript?

Comment: `[{'cars':car1, 'cars':car2, 'cars':car3}]` ==> `[{'cars':car3}]`

Comment: Have you tried using `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: your code is behaving perfectly normal, you're replacing the value of "cars" by car1 car 2 car3.... you need to store them in different properties to be able to get them all.

Comment: What you want to do? Insert `myObj` into array? If yes, just do `[myObj]`

Comment: You have to push a new object in your array, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `var json = JSON.stringify(jsObject)` and `var jsObject = JSON.parse("json string")`

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over object and push it into array:

```
var myObj = data.response.carTypes;
var myArr = [];
for (var key in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      myArr.push(myObj[key]);
    }
}
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the array to JSON using `var myJsonArray = JSON.stringify(myArray)`.

If you're doing this conversion in an older browser, you can use a [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295515/2639697).

In order to get your array from the JSON you created, you can use:

`var myArray = JSON.parse(myJsonArray)`

Also, bear in mind that when you use the same key for several objects in your JSON, [the last key with the same name is the one that is going to be used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5306792/2639697).

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to use javascript object.
say

```
$scope.myArray = [];

var carlist.cars="";
var carlist={};
```

carlist is a object which cars is a property
then you can try this way:

```
var myObj = data.response.carTypes;
for (var key in myObj) {
    if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      carlist.cars=myObj[key];
      myArray.push(carlist);
      console.log(myArray);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a new array and push a new object to it in each iteration:

```
$scope.myArray = [];
for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    $scope.myArray.push({cars:myObj[key]});
  }
};
```

**Demo:**

```js
var myObj = {
  a: "Car1",
  b: "Car2",
  c: "Car3"
};
var carsArray = [];
for (var key in myObj) {
  if (myObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    carsArray.push({cars:myObj[key]});
  }
};
console.log(carsArray);
```