# How can I parse the array objects inside this JSON list in VBA?

Tags: json, vba, excel, parsing

My JSON is:

```
{"totalCount":431,"messages":[],"results":[{"aliasList":["User Id","Name","last name"],"results":[[71512,"joe","adams"],[23445,"jack","wilson"],[34566,jill,goodman]],"executionDate":151134568428}],"Class":"com.zoho.controlpanel.reports.ReportsItemVO"}
```

I want to parse the objects e.g. `[71512,"joe","adams"]` inside the second `results` key.

And this is my attempt to call the JSON-VBA parser:

```
Public Sub exceljson()
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, i As Integer
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
http.Open "GET", "http://controlpanel.zoho.verio/rest/reports/search/reports-call-center-my-assignments", False
http.send
Set JSON = ParseJson(ParseJson(http.responseText)("results"))("results")
Debug.Print JSON
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON
Sheets(5).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("1")
Sheets(5).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("2")
Sheets(5).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("3")
i = i + 1
Next
MsgBox ("complete")
End Sub
```

I am getting error

> run-time error 450 wrong number of arguments

What should I modify in my parser to properly parse these objects into a spreadsheet?

Comment: Try to enclose the JSON in square brackets.

Comment: Also, this jill,goodman should be "jill","goodman"

Comment: @QHarr yeah i know, it is an example for a JSON i have but a large dataset. the architecture is the same

Comment: You already had an answer here 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48703168/cannot-iterate-when-parsing-html-table-using-json-vba/48715323#48715323

Comment: @TimWilliams I’m sorry my mistake, for some reason I didn’t see the new edits on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have run the following code which is corrected and it is working fine. I was unable to open the URL but I have paste the jason string given by you in cell "P1". jill,goodman was manually covered in double quotes as it was wrong. I have commented certain part of code which you can use whenever it is required.

```
Public Sub exceljson()
Dim http As Object, JSON As Object, Item As Variant
Dim i As Integer

'Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
jsnStr = Range("P1")
'http.Open "GET", "http://controlpanel.zoho.verio/rest/reports/search/reports-call-center-my-assignments", False
'http.send
'Debug.Print http.responseText
'Set JSON = ParseJson(http.responseText)
Set JSON = ParseJson(jsnStr)

'Fetching data
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON("results")(1)("results")
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item(1)
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item(2)
    Sheets(2).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item(3)
    i = i + 1
Next
Set JSON = Nothing
Set http = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Do you mind explaining why it is JSON("results")(1)("results")? I can see that results is nested within results at index 1 but why is the end "results" needed please?

Comment: Great question. Please parse the this json string on http://jsoneditoronline.org/  You will see square brackets and curly brackets after each name. square brackets represents it is an array while curly brackets represents it is an object. The data is saved in "results" >> "0" >> "results" node. The ("results")(1)  specify the 1st index inside the first "results" array. Hence we are using JSON("results")(1)("results").

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Welcome @QHarr . I think this can be useful for you. https://codingislove.com/excel-json/