# How to have same propertyname appear twice?

Tags: c#, json

I am currently trying to write a json string but seem to have an issue with it having same json properties multiple time in the json string?

```
  "{\"internalName\":\"propulsion\",\"internalName\":\"descriptionsas\"}"
```

This ignores the second entry the first entry, since the second one overwrites it... how do i store both in the json string an deserialize it such that can get both strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306741/do-json-keys-need-to-be-unique

Comment: This got closed off as a duplicate of a generic question about whether JSON supports duplicate property names, but you tagged this [tag:system.text.json].  Do you have a *specific* question for this API?  If so can you elaborate a little?  Are you trying to **deserialize** JSON with duplicated property names, or **serialize** JSON with duplicated property names?

Comment: no @dbc -  I am using `system.text.json` and thought it might have been a limitation - instead it was something more simple than that.. but the tag is misleading  - i will remove it.