# How to parse complex json to c# .net classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

my json is as given below. i need to convert it into c# class. Please note all values will be different in actual scenario.

```
{
  'aa-AA': {
    lanCODE: 'aa-AA',
    genNames: {
      female: ['Wavenet'],
      male: ['Bavenet', 'Bavenet'],
    },
    default: 'Wavenet',
    systemLocale: ['ara', 'aru', 'are', 'aro', 'arh', 'arm', 'arq', 'ark'],
    name: 'xxxx',
  },
  'aa-AA': {
    lanCODE: 'aa-AA',
    genNames: {
      female: ['Wavenet'],
      male: ['Bavenet', 'Bavenet'],
    },
    default: 'Wavenet',
    systemLocale: ['ara', 'aru', 'are', 'aro', 'arh', 'arm', 'arq', 'ark'],
    name: 'xxxx',
  },
  'aa-AA': {
    lanCODE: 'aa-AA',
    genNames: {
      female: ['Wavenet'],
      male: ['Bavenet', 'Bavenet'],
    },
    default: 'Wavenet',
    systemLocale: ['ara', 'aru', 'are', 'aro', 'arh', 'arm', 'arq', 'ark'],
    name: 'xxxx',
  }
 }
```

Comment: Does the complexity of the JSON cames from the fact that it's ill formated and not valid ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-generate a C# class file from a JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611674/how-to-auto-generate-a-c-sharp-class-file-from-a-json-string)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: "You need" is different than what you have tried.  Please post what you have tried in c# and the challenges it has presented to to so we may help you fix it.

Comment: Format error are : using single quote `'` instead of double quote, Property name must be double quoted `"`. Trailling comma are illegal ([1,2,3 **,** ]=> illegal)

Comment: step 1: make sure your JSON is valid. step 2: ***write at least some code yourself***. step 3: ask again when you have a _specific_ problem, instead of a generic task that's been asked and answered thousands of times before.

Comment: And multiple properties named `"aa-AA"`, while it's legal (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5306741/do-json-keys-need-to-be-unique). It's undefined behavior, where the last properties will eraze the previous value.

Comment: Not that a complex json. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial property is almost certainly meant to be a dictionary key, so I would go with something like this:

```
public class Language
{
    [JsonProperty("lanCODE")]
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    
    public string Default { get; set; }

    public List<string> SystemLocale { get; set; }

    public GenNames GenNames { get; set; }
}

public class GenNames
{
    public List<string> Female { get; set; }
    public List<string> Male { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialise like this:

```
var languages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Language>>(json);
```